Correct inheritance of methods from dataclass in Python
I'm quite new to dataclasses and OOP in Python and I have been trying to figure out how to inheritance works. Before anything, I am really sorry if my question has been asked in one way or another, I really tried to look for similar questions but there is nothing out there that answered me. So apologies beforehand if there is anything unclear.
Basically I want to achieve the following:

metadata.py

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class IngestionMetadata:
    file: str
    sheet_name: str
    col_converters: dict
    col_names: list = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'col_names', list(self.col_converters.keys()))
    
    @classmethod
    def get_columns(cls):
        return list(cls.col_converters.keys())



@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ProductGroupLookup(IngestionMetadata):
    file: str = 'product_group_table.xlsx'
    sheet_name: str = 'INGESTION'
    col_converters: dict = field(default_factory= lambda: {
        'Product 1': pl.String,
        'Product 2': pl.String,
        'Product 3': pl.String,
        'Product Category Code 4': pl.String
    })




My goal is to be able to import the module from another script like:
from metadata import IngestionMetadata as im


product_cols = im.ProductGroupLookup.get_columns() # Should output ['Product 1', 'Product 2'...]



I tried already separating the classes into subclasses or just putting them all inside the base class but without success. I would appreciate some guidance.

Method inheritance for dataclasses works just like method inheritance for any other class. It doesn't make sense that get_columns is a classmethod instead of a regular instance method, but that issue doesn't have anything to do with the use of dataclasses.

If you are hard-coding all instance variables in the subclass, that's a sign you just want an instance of IngestionMetaData, rather than a subclass whose instances would all be effectively identical to each other.

Thank you! Actually what you say makes total sense.
